# Rails Nested from plus join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following models and running rails 3.01:

```
# file: app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, :through => :product_categories
  has_many :product_categories, :dependent => :destroy
  accept_nested_attributes_for :product_categories
end

# file: app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :through => :product_categories
  has_many :product_categories, :dependent => :destroy
end

# file: app/models/product_category.rb
class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end
```

ProductCategory is my join table. What do I call in my products form? Do I build on the Categories table or the ProdcutCategories table? Im just really confused on how/which models Im supposed to nest in my products from. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is already configured to accept attributes for the `products_categories` association. In your form just reference it like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :products_categories do |pc| %>
  # fields go here
```

Remember that you will need to build new objects for the `products_categories` association before this form will render anything:

```
products.products_categories.build
```

Comment: I added to my products form: <%= f.fields_for :product_categories do |pc| %>
 <%= pc.label :primary_category_name %>
   <%= pc.text_field :primary_category_name, :size => 65 %>
   <%= pc.label :primary_category_id %>
   <%= pc.text_field :primary_category_id %> <%end%>                                                                   and in my products controller: def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.product_categories.build end. Im receiving "undefined method `primary_category_name' "

Comment: Your `ProductCategory` objects don't respond to `primary_category_name`. That's another problem entirely.